# How to host an API (written in Flask-SQLAlchemy) to communicate with a Docker-ized MySQL container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, sqlalchemy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

## Context

I have a backend and API written in Python and Flask-SQLAlchemy. I use Flask-SQLAlchemy to define tables for a MySQL database, and my API routes access these tables. Previously, all my development has been on my local machine and my Flask-SQLAlchemy communicated with a local SQLite database. I currently have a Docker container with a MySQL image which contains an empty MySQL database.

## What I Am Trying To Accomplish

I would like to host this API online, as well as host the Docker container (which contains a MySQL database) online. The Flask-SQLAlchemy API should communicate with the hosted MySQL database.

## Options I've Considered

To my understanding, there are several options to host my API and MySQL database online.

- For my API, I can either host my API onto AWS Elastic Beanstalk, or onto Docker then onto EC2.
- For my MySQL database, I would like to host it onto Docker then onto EC2.

The following is how I assume I can approach this:

[image]

## Problem

Should I host my Flask-SQLAlchemy API on Elastic Beanstalk, or on Docker then onto EC2? My main goal is to have my hosted API talk to a MySQL database hosted on Docker.

Comment: You can have docker containers on EB if you want. have you considered that?

Comment: Running MySQL in Docker is typical for local dev, not production. Why not use a MySQL hosted service? There are plenty to choose from and they deal with uptime, upgrades, etc.

Comment: @Marcin can you elaborate on that? Are you saying I should host my API onto Docker, my MySQL database on Docker, and host both docker containers directly onto EB as opposed to on ECS?

Comment: @Chase Interesting, I will look into a MySQL hosted service to host my MySQL database. How do you think I should host my API?

Comment: EB [supports docker applications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker.html), so instead of deciding whether to use EB or Docker on ECS, you can use both. I'm not saying you should, but its a possibility.

Comment: @Marcin Thank you for the input. As it currently stands, I will look into a MySQL hosted service for my database, but am still unclear on how I should host my Flask-SQLAlchemy API.

Comment: If its already containerized, literally any service that runs containers will do. Every host has a service that accepts a container. There are also services which accept Python (and other langs) apps specifically and will containerize them for you, Google App Engine, DigitalOcean App Platform, Heroku, etc. The only acceptable answer here is the platform that you choose to use. What we all do is trial and error; sign up for the free version, deploy, try it out and see if you like it.